# Unable to update and upgrade Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: apt, upgrade, 22.04

I have the following errors when trying to upgrade my Ubuntu:

133 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,447 kB/207 MB of archives.
After this operation, 13.5 MB disk space will be freed.

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security/main amd64 libssl1.1 amd64 1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.6
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Any idea how to fix them?

Comment: Try turning off IPv6 if you have it active. Seems as there is a problem using it for the update / upgrade.

Comment: There is one obvious problem: Your sources list is messed up. You have *impish* repos connected to your *jammy* system. As a starting point, please edit your post and paste in the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: To add some context to @OrganicMarble 's comments, Impish is the name of Ubuntu version 21.10, that came out on the 10th month of 2021. This version of Ubuntu has reached end of its life and is not supported. There fore the Impish repositories have been archived. If you are trying to upgrade Ubuntu from 21.10 to 22.04, you have to follow special instructions. See the link below.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades   *Your title & tag shows 22.04, but paste shows only 21.10*

Answer (score 1):

Although I am new to Ubuntu 22.04, one thing I have noticed is that it is really strict on not having any loose ends before proceeding with updates.

Make sure that this command "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade" returns "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded."

Then you could try "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade".

Comment: I didn't down vote; but `sudo apt update` will have issues with the *impish* or 21.10 source and then `apt upgrade` will never be run. We weren't given the command & full output of the command in the OPs (*Original Posters*) question, but it matches a 21.10 system and not *jammy* or 22.04 meaning what the OP is doing is incorrect (*no command shown*), or they have incorrect sources if running *jammy* or 22.04 as stated as *impish* is EOL (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/)

Comment: If they're running *impish* as their paste implies; they need to *release-upgrade* asap... If they're running *jammy* or 22.04 as their title & tag shows, they need to correct their sources & remove the *impish* or 21.10 sources, then they'll fix their issue with a simple `sudo apt update` - however given an *impish* package was selected in the first place, something else *unseen* in OPs details also exists (*likely a mistake or unwise decision made by OP*)

Comment: The OP's situation seems not amenable to the use of `dist-upgrade`. Their problem is different.